# Microsoft graph API request on behalf of Application

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

My organization has implemented authorization using Oauth on our APIs utilizing Azure AD B2C. We have different applications registered and have given them app roles that we ensure are on the JWT for authorization, as well as other claims we use for validation.

My question is it best practice to then use our own graph API credentials to handle changes on the backend of our API, or should we be using theirs?

For example, an application wants to edit a user in B2C. They call us with their JWT scoped to our backend API. We validate it and update the user. Should the update be performed using our own graph API credentials, or should we be performing some form of token exchange to obtain a graph token tied to their credentials somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure AD B2C doesn't support on-the-behalf-of flow yet for API's. This being said, there is value of this design with complex resource API delegation models. This requirement generally is something that evolves from mature services due to acquisitions or just increasing data points from multiple sources but requires scale architecture.

For simple services that don't have 100's/1,000's of resource API's, then a simpler design (not requiring token exchange) makes sense.

Using something like Azure API Manager is ideally to put in front of your application. This gives you the typical control that an APIM provides. Other things it provides are:

- DNS control for API endpoints that are not service dependent
- Ability to do fallback logic by controlling endpoints and automation
- A/B testing and release controlled by DNS
- Requires no application dev change to update endpoints

Depending on industry, you may require/need OBO - for having the authorization Web API (API-1) not obtain user data in the original token - and data is in the 2nd token (API-2)i.e. resource API. Mostly it's a design requirement on how the API resources requires. I'd recommend looking at the OAuth token exchange protocol to see what makes sense for you. It's important to understand OBO does not align with the token exchange protocol.